# Unable to deploy to Google App Engine : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, firebase

Got this error while trying to setup [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

> Preparing to deploy:  Created staging directory at:
>   'C:\Users\Parag\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg4808135439637212840.tmp'
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max
>   supported is Java 7: com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$1.class in
>   G:_work\testproject\war\WEB-INF\lib\firebase-admin-4.0.0.jar

[image]

App Engine SDK version: 1.9.34

Eclipse version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)

Java Compiler Version Set to 1.7
[image: Java Compiler Version]

Have anyone encountered this error, please help

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Were you able to find a solution somehow?

Comment: @droidster not yet brother :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this is a known issue based on their [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java) for firebase-admin version 4.0.0 (November 7, 2016) and version 4.0.1 (November 8, 2016):

> ISSUE: This version was compiled for Java 8 and does not support Java 7. This will be fixed in an upcoming release.

I guess we'll have to wait ;)

---

UPDATE:

As per their [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java), it is now fixed in version 4.0.2 - November 15, 2016:

> FIXED This update restores Java 7 compatibilty for the Admin Java SDK.

Comment: Please provide context for the link you are sharing. Although the link you shared may indeed be very helpful, it is advisable to rather capture the key aspects of the shared article that respond to the question. 
This way, even if the link is removed your answer will still be relevant and helpful.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait then :(

Comment: It is fixed now ;)

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it appears as though the firebase-admin-sdk is intended to be used on the Google Flexible Environment instead of the Standard Environment.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/flexible-for-standard-users

A comparable package for the Standard Environment would be firebase-server-sdk.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-server-sdk

However, references to the original server sdk documentation now forward to the admin sdk documentation.  So, perhaps they will release an update to the Standard Environment that supports Java 8, or an update to the admin sdk that works on Java 7.

Comment: That's good to hear.  I am currently using the firebase-server-sdk, but may try again with the admin sdk as it provides additional features and more fine-grained control.